# Having trouble understanding assembly code and use of GDB

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb

This is my assembly code:

```
    0x08048bd0 <+0>:    sub    $0x2c,%esp
    0x08048bd3 <+3>:    movl   $0x0,0x1c(%esp)
    0x08048bdb <+11>:   lea    0x1c(%esp),%eax
    0x08048bdf <+15>:   mov    %eax,0x8(%esp)
    0x08048be3 <+19>:   movl   $0x804a439,0x4(%esp)
    0x08048beb <+27>:   mov    0x30(%esp),%eax
    0x08048bef <+31>:   mov    %eax,(%esp)
 => 0x08048bf2 <+34>:   call   0x8048870 <__isoc99_sscanf@plt>
    0x08048bf7 <+39>:   cmp    $0x1,%eax
    0x08048bfa <+42>:   je     0x8048c01 <phase_1+49>
    0x08048bfc <+44>:   call   0x8049455 <explode_bomb>
    0x08048c01 <+49>:   cmpl   $0x19a,0x1c(%esp)
    0x08048c09 <+57>:   je     0x8048c10 <phase_1+64>
    0x08048c0b <+59>:   call   0x8049455 <explode_bomb>
    0x08048c10 <+64>:   add    $0x2c,%esp
    0x08048c13 <+67>:   ret
```

I'm working a binary bomb, it gives the assembly code from which I have to find the correct input to defuse it. I'm new to GDB and assembly so I'm having trouble with his particular part of the code.

I've set break point at phase_1, but when I use ni to traverse the code the bomb would explode when i get to where `<explode_bomb>` it's called, is there any way to deal with this? I understand that `eax` has to be equal to 1 in order to make the bomb not explode. I'm confused by what's going on in the first function called, when I type si it gives something looks like this.

```
 => 0x08048870 <+0>:    jmp    *0x804d058
    0x08048876 <+6>:    push   $0x98
    0x0804887b <+11>:   jmp    0x8048730
```

Comment: Don't step into that function. it's pointless. You can see it's `sscanf`. Do you know C? Do you know how `sscanf` works?

Comment: `jmp    *0x804d058` is the PLT stub for the call to the libc sscanf function.